# How to alignment picture in cell in a table

Tags: tables

I have a problem with alignment one picture in a table. I can not understand, How to alignment picture in cell in a table. Please help me.
Thank you in advance.

**LATEX**

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
            \begin{tabular}{cccccccc}
                \toprule
                Objekt & Treffer & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Ausreißer}\\
                %\cmidrule{3-4}
                & & Objekt & Platzierung \\
                \midrule
                \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{Bueste_1.jpg}} & 6 
                    & \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{Bueste_8.jpg}} & 25 \\
                \midrule
                    \multirow{2}{*}{                \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Bueste_2.jpg}} 
                    & \multirow{2}{*}{5}    &   \includegraphics[width=0.08\textwidth]{Bueste_7.jpg} & 13\\
                    \multicolumn{2}{c}{}    & \includegraphics[width=0.08\textwidth]{Bueste_8.jpg} & 24 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\caption{Mit Normalisierung}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

latex source to table
https://www.dropbox.com/s/lvfm9po4xlid0pp/tabelle.tex

picture source
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ds3kih9nuq601n5/img.rar

Answer (score 4):

I did several things here.  First, I created a macro `\centergraphics` that is basically an `\includegraphics` with the baseline going through the midpoint of the picture (rather than the base of the picture).  I also used stacks instead of `multirow`s to achieve the effect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\let\tw\textwidth
\newsavebox\tempbox
\newcommand\centergraphics[2][]{%
  \sbox\tempbox{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \raisebox{-.5\ht\tempbox}{\usebox{\tempbox}}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
            \begin{tabular}{cccccccc}
                \toprule
                Objekt & Treffer & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Ausreier}\\
                %\cmidrule{3-4}
                & & Objekt & Platzierung \\
                \midrule
  \centergraphics[width=0.2\tw,height=.2\tw]{Bueste_1.jpg}
& 6 
                    &
\centergraphics[width=0.1\tw,height=.1\tw]{Bueste_8.jpg}
& 25 \\
                \midrule
\centergraphics[width=0.2\tw,height=.2\tw]{Bueste_2.jpg}
                    & 5 &
\stackanchor{%
\centergraphics[width=0.08\tw,height=.08\tw]{Bueste_7.jpg}%
}{%
\centergraphics[width=0.08\tw,height=.08\tw]{Bueste_8.jpg}%
}& \stackanchor[.06\tw]{13}{24}\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\caption{Mit Normalisierung}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you. But I do not understand,why it is not working by me.

Comment: @user2902946 One possibility is that you don't have the `stackengine` package loaded.  The other is that your version of it is out of date.  Current version should be 3.24.

Answer (score 1):

This is a workaround solution based on OP's code. Here `multirow{8}{*}{...}` is assumed for (2,1) entry wher the OP used `multirow{2}{*}{...}`. Since (2,3) entry contains two figures alinged vertically, so `multirow{4}{*}{...}` is used for each.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=10pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
            \begin{tabular}{cccc}
                \toprule
                Objekt & Treffer & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Ausreißer}\\
                %\cmidrule{3-4}
                & & Objekt & Platzierung \\
                \midrule
                \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{Bueste_1.jpg}} & 6 
                    & \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{Bueste_8.jpg}} & 25 \\
                \midrule
\multirow{8}{*}{\includegraphics[scale=0.9]{Bueste_2.jpg}} &\multirow{8}{*}{5}  &\multirow{4}{*}{\includegraphics[width=0.08\textwidth]{Bueste_7.jpg}} & \multirow{4}{*}{13} \\[2cm]
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} &  \multirow{4}{*}{\includegraphics[width=0.08\textwidth]{Bueste_8.jpg}} &  \multirow{4}{*}{24} \\[1.3cm]
 \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\caption{Mit Normalisierung}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```